# Rows in tkinter grid

Tags: python, tkinter, grid

I want to use the grid method in `tkinter` to show some data I have in a database. When I define the `__init__` method I have to set up a specific number of rows, which are similar to each other. But, as the value of the rows will be taken from a database, I can not define precisely the number of rows I will need.

Until now, my only solution is too set a maximum number of rows in the `__init__` method, which I can control. But this solution does not show all the information on the screen. Any help will be welcome.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#------------------------------------------------------------

__title__= 'Control'
__date__ = '02/07/2017'
__version__ = '0.0.1'

from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class Panel():
    def __init__(self):

        self.root = Tk()
        self.root. title('Control V' + __version__)
        self.root.geometry('500x400')
        self.root.configure(bg='beige')
        self.root.minsize(400,300)

        self.window = ttk.Frame(self.root, borderwidth=2, relief="raised",
                                padding=(10,10) )
        self.window.grid(column=0, row=0)
        self.window.option_add("*Font", "Helvetica 12")

        # Row 0
        self.r0c0 = ttk.Label(self.window, text="Header", padding=(1,1))
        self.r0c0.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3)

        # Row 1
        counter = 1
        # From db : o = {'Name': 'Zara', 'Age': 7, 'Class': 'First'}
        o = {'Name': 'Zara', 'Age': 7, 'Class': 'First'}

        self.r1c0 = ttk.Label(self.window, text=o['Name'], padding=(1,1))
        self.r1c0.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.r1c1 = ttk.Label(self.window, text=o['Age'], padding=(1,1))
        self.r1c1.grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.r1c2 = ttk.Label(self.window, text=o['Class'], padding=(1,1))
        self.r1c2.grid(row=1, column=2)

        # Row 2, Row 3, ... All are similar to Row 1
        counter = 2
        # From db : o = {'Name': 'Ezra', 'Age': 5, 'Class': 'First'}
        o = {'Name': 'Ezra', 'Age': 5, 'Class': 'First'}

        self.r2c0 = ttk.Label(self.window, text=o['Name'], padding=(1,1))
        self.r2c0.grid(row=2, column=0)
        self.r2c1 = ttk.Label(self.window, text=o['Age'], padding=(1,1))
        self.r2c1.grid(row=2, column=1)
        self.r2c2 = ttk.Label(self.window, text=o['Class'], padding=(1,1))
        self.r2c2.grid(row=2, column=2)

        # Row 3, Row 4, ... All are similar to Row 1 & 2.
        # Can I make a loop where n is unknown at definition

        # All set
        self.root.mainloop()

def main():
    my_panel = Panel()
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Do you get the DB data in the `__init__` like you did here ?

Comment: Do you really need to keep references to all of those Labels? If so, you should be saving them in some kind of collection, eg a list of lists, not giving each Label a separate name.

Comment: I think @PM2Ring makes a good point about creating attributes for every row and column that's displayed (like `self.r1c0`, `self.r1c1`, etc). How is the rest of your code going to know what they are if there's a variable number of them? Reminds me a little bit of the advice in the blog article [**_Keep data out of your variable names_**](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html).

Comment: @TrakJohnson, yes at least at this stage but I should move it out.

Comment: @PM 2Ring, Thanks, I will follow your advice

Comment: @martineau Thanks, I will follow your advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built-in [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#enumerate) function lets you loop over a sequence and get both the sequence item and a sequential index number. By default, the indices start at zero, but you can supply an alternate starting index.

To make the code easier to read, I've put the Label creation and packing code into a separate method.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk 

class Panel:
    def __init__(self, field_names, database):
        self.root = tk.Tk()

        self.window = ttk.Frame(self.root, borderwidth=2, 
            relief="raised", padding=(10,10))
        self.window.grid()

        # Create the header row
        for col, field_name in enumerate(field_names):
            self.add_field(field_name, 0, col, background='#ccf')

        # Create the data rows
        for row, record in enumerate(database, 1):
            for col, field_name in enumerate(field_names):
                self.add_field(record[field_name], row, col)

        self.root.mainloop()

    def add_field(self, value, row, col, background=''):
        label = ttk.Label(self.window, text=value, background=background,
            borderwidth=1, relief="raised", padding=(1,1))
        label.grid(row=row, column=col, sticky='ew')


def main():
    field_names = ('Name', 'Age', 'Class')

    database = [
        {'Name': 'Zara', 'Age': 7, 'Class': 'First'},
        {'Name': 'Ezra', 'Age': 5, 'Class': 'First'},
        {'Name': 'Amy', 'Age': 6, 'Class': 'Second'},
        {'Name': 'David', 'Age': 10, 'Class': 'Third'},
    ]

    my_panel = Panel(field_names, database)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you. This was what I was looking for. Now I have to implement it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Displaying a variable number of things in a `tkinter` GUI is usually handled with `Scrollbar` which can be attached to `Listbox`, `Canvas`, `Text`, or `Entry` widgets. In this case a `Listbox` seems appropriate so here's an example of using it:

```
__title__= 'Control'
__date__ = '02/07/2017'
__version__ = '0.0.1'

from itertools import cycle
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

# Some test data
db = [
    {'Name': 'Zara', 'Age': 7, 'Class': 'First'},
    {'Name': 'Ezra', 'Age': 5, 'Class': 'First'},
    {'Name': 'Bob', 'Age': 8, 'Class': 'Third'},
    {'Name': 'Mary', 'Age': 6, 'Class': 'Second'},
]

class Panel():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root. title('Control V' + __version__)
        self.root.geometry('500x400')
        self.root.configure(bg='beige')
        self.root.minsize(400,300)

        self.window = ttk.Frame(self.root, borderwidth=2, relief="raised",
                                padding=(10,10))
        self.window.grid(column=0, row=0)
        self.window.option_add("*Font", "Helvetica 12")

        self.listbox = Listbox(self.window)
        self.listbox.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N+E+S+W)

        self.scrollbar = Scrollbar(self.window)
        self.scrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N+S)

        self.listbox.config(yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar.set)
        self.scrollbar.config(command=self.listbox.yview)

        # Row 0
        self.listbox.insert(END, "Header")

        # Simulate getting many rows from database by repeating them
        endless_data = cycle(db)
        for i in range(20):
            row = next(endless_data)
            line = '{Name:5} {Age:2} {Class}'.format(**row)
            self.listbox.insert(END, line)

        # All set
        self.root.mainloop()

def main():
    my_panel = Panel()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This is what it looks like:

[image: screenshot of listbox]

Comment: Thank you, I did not think about Scrollbar as it only shows a certain amount of rows. But it shows me a path to follow.